FETCH API, invalid JSON
I try to use the FETCH API to handover Data to a php Programm. But in the JS console i keep getting this error.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "

<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON

const category = document.getElementById('genreSelect').value;
const js1 = '{"genre": "' + category + '"}';
const js2 = JSON.stringify(js1); 

fetch("button.php", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: { category: js2 }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {

               

                
                

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });

<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

   
    

    if(isset($_POST)){
        $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

        $kate = json_decode($data, true);
        $kat = $kate[0];


        $every = array();

echo json_encode($every);

I validated the JSON, but it was fine, so I ran out of possibilities left to do.
I wrote a method, that checks if it is a valid json on the JS side. The PHP could not decode it.
function isJsonString(str) {
try {
    JSON.parse(str);
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
return true;

}
And it returns true, and it is received as Object on the PHP side.
I verified, if it is a valid json on the php side, but apprently, the jason_decode() function return null.
$kate = json_decode($data, true);

    if($kate == null){
        echo "null";

    }

I have no idea, why it cannot be encoded, specifically because we veriefied in js, that it is valid.

Use the browser DevTools to inspect the response.

Your PHP code is missing a closing }

The php cannot decode the json, that is the problem. But I don't know why, because I checked, if it valid on the JS side before fetching it, and it is valid.

How do you check that? So you inspected the request/response in your DevTools? What is the JSON you're sending? What is the response from PHP? You can [edit] your question and post there

Looks like php is probably returning HTML instead, which is quite likely because it threw an error. Check the Response to the fetch() request in the browser's Developer Tools and see what was actually in there.

To be clear: the error is coming from javascript, not php. Js can't decode what php returned. It isn't a problem with what JS sent (which is what you seem to have assumed)

It throws an error, because it could not decode the JSON. But the question is, why it cannot decode the JSON

Because, like I said, it isn't JSON. Look at the error message - it's quoted the start of the text it can't decode, which is clearly some HTML. Did you do what I said yet and check the Response to the fetch() request using your browser's Network tool? That will tell you exactly what php really returned.

JavaScript does not serialize the object for you automatically...
fetch("button.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    // this does not work
    body: { category: js2 }
    // you need to serialize the whole body
    body: JSON.stringify({ category: js2 })
})

So, your php backend will very likely receive something like [object] which is what JavaScript does when you try to convert an object to a string. But this is invalid JSON obviously.
As suggested by Olivier, it is very helpful to look in the DevTools of your browser. There you will see what you are actually sending to PHP.
A comment to your verification, you are verifying the wrong thing here. What you would need to verify is the whole body and not only a nested key in an object. If you passed { category: js2 } to your isJsonString() it would throw an error because you are passing an object and not a (JSON) string.

You should have answered the question IMO. Please [edit] to mention what works.
